# Error in module: Uses clause is missing or incorrect

Tags: delphi, exception, web-applications, delphi-xe

I am trying to create a web server application under RAD Studio Delphi XE.

When I click on `New -> others`. I get a dialog window with options. I choose VCL for the Web. Then, I get another dialog window with "standalone application" and "ISAPI" options.

If I choose standalone application option, the compiler doesn't have any problem, but if I choose ISAPI, I get the "error in module: Uses clause is missing or incorrect" exception even before it creates the project.

Does anyone know why and how to resolve this problem?

Comment: Delphi does not include anything .NET (even in XE); that's handled by Delphi Prism. The .net tag doesn't apply here. Regarding your question, the steps above work fine in D2007, and XE2/3 don't include "VCL for the Web" any longer (it's just IntraWeb now).

Comment: @KenWhite, I stand corrected. Thank you for your comment. I have "Embarcadero® RAD Studio XE Version 15.0.3953.35171 Copyright © 2010 Embarcadero Technologies, Inc" on my system. And it does have "VCL for the WEB" under Delphi Projects --> VCL for the web --> VCL for the web application wizard. I am not even going to guess. So, I just checked my compiler to make sure.

Comment: `VCL for the Web` isn't `.net`. :-) .NET refers to the MS .NET framework. The tags have definitions to them, which should help you decide which ones to use. The fact that `VCL for the Web` isn't in XE2 or XE3 probably won't be an issue, though, as IntraWeb (the `VCL for the Web` in a couple of Delphi versions) is still there; I don't know if they're directly compatible, however.